# Active Record Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-record

Se eu tenho um modelo Avaliacao e eu fizer `avaliacaoes = Avaliacao.all` e depois `avaliacoes.where("score = ?", 3)`. No primeiro comando o Rails busca todas as avaliações, o que acontece no segundo comando? O Rails vai buscar as avaliações da base ou ele usa as avaliações que estão carregadas na memória?

Comment: Em Rails 4 o `where` methodo aceita um hash: `Avaliacao.where(score: 1)` - você não precisa `all`.

Answer (score 2):

No Rails 4, diferente do 3, ao chamar o método `all` o Active Record não retorna um `Array`, mas um objeto filho de `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Uma vez que as queries retornam essa `Relation`, agora podemos encadear as nossas queries de forma que elas produzam apenas um sql:

```
Client.all.where("name = ?", "Juliano")
=> Client Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE (name = 'Juliano')
```

Porém, fazendo como você perguntou, o ActiveRecord vai gerar duas queries, uma vez que elas não estão encadeadas. O objeto avaliacoes é uma Relation, de forma que ele vai sim fazer segunda uma chamada ao banco.

Para que seja acesso único no banco, você deve encadear as duas chamadas. Se não for possível, você pode lidar com o resultado já em memória com o método `select`:

```
avaliacaoes = Avaliacao.all
avaliacoes.select {|a| a.score == 3}
```

**Errata**

Conforme apontado pelo @GuiGS, parte da minha resposta deve ser corrigida. Quando você usa a Relation mais de uma vez no mesmo método, ele será avaliado somente no final, logo o seu código vai fazer apenas uma busca no banco, apesar das chamadas não estarem visivelmente encadeadas (obj.metodo1.metodo2) elas serão avaliadas somente quando os dados forem necessários.

Só é importante ressaltar que se você possuir várias condições, algumas podem ser ignoradas.

```
avaliacaoes = Avaliacao.all
avaliacoes.where("score = ?", 3)
avaliacoes.where("score = ?", 2)
```

Vai gerar

```
=> Avaliacao Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "avaliacoes".* FROM "avaliacoes" WHERE (score = 2)
```

Desculpem o engano, caí nessa porque testei a minha resposta diretamente no console, aí cada avaliação era feita de imediato. My bad! ;)

Comment: Eu perguntei porque estou fazendo um algoritmo de recomendação, e tenho 1800 itens na base e 6000 avaliações que pode ser positiva ou negativa. Eu tenho como premissa que vou ter que trazer todos os dados do banco para realizar o algoritmo. Creio que seja melhor fazer apenas 1 consulta e utilizar o #select para 'segregar' os dados. Você acha que essa é a melhor abordagem? Antes eu estava fazendo `Item.all {|item| item.likes ... item.dislikes}` e para cada item era no mínimo 2 consultas no banco que da cerca de 3600 consultas rsrs

Comment: 3600 consultas? Sem dúvida é melhor manter em memória e trabalhar os dados com selects e maps! :D

Comment: @Juliano, parte de sua resposta não está correta. A forma com que o Awkward fez é um encadeamento e só  vai gerar uma query no banco.

Comment: @GuiGS você tem razão. Vou corrigir a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Nesta sua situação acho mais válido trazer as avaliações filtradas já, usando o `.where(condition)` que assim é gerado o sql corretamente e faz uma consulta somente, exemplo:

```
Avaliacoes.where("score = ?", 3)
```

Para o caso da recomendação, de uma olha no método `.partition` da classe [Enumerable](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/partition), com ele você irá receber como retorno, dois arrays, um caso a condição passada seja true, e outro caso seja false, exemplo:

```
(1..6).partition {|v| v.even? }
#=> [[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]]
```